# meaning of multi-interval

Tags: interval-arithmetic

According to the following definition, a multi-interval is just a line segment for n=1, a square region for n=2, a cubic for n=3, and so on so forth, correct?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily a square region ($n=2$) and a cubic region ($n=3$), but rectangle and a box. For higher dimensions the word used seems to be [hyperrectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperrectangle).

A multi-interval is often written as for example $[a_1, b_1] \times (a_2, b_2) \times \cdots \times (a_n, b_n]$.

Comment: An old geometric term for it  (without regard to co-ordinate axes) is $n$-dimensional orthogonal parallelipiped.